# How could i parse this Json object to a Java object?

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to parse Json object to a Java object but i'm having issues with one of its keys.
This is the key i'm trying to parse:

```
"formats":{"application/x-mobipocket-ebook":"http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/84.kindle.images",
"text/plain; charset=utf-8":"http://www.gutenberg.org/files/84/84-0.zip",
"text/html; charset=utf-8":"http://www.gutenberg.org/files/84/84-h/84-h.htm",
"application/rdf+xml":"http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/84.rdf",
"application/epub+zip":"http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/84.epub.images",
"application/zip":"http://www.gutenberg.org/files/84/84-h.zip",
"image/jpeg":"http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/84/pg84.cover.small.jpg"}
```

So i have the Java class like this:

```
public class Format {

    @JsonProperty("application/x-mobipocket-ebook")
    private String ebook;

    @JsonProperty("text/plain; charset=utf-8")
    private String textPlain;

    @JsonProperty("text/html; charset=utf-8")
    private String textHtml;

    @JsonProperty("application/rdf+xml")
    private String textXml;

    @JsonProperty("application/epub+zip")
    private String epubZip;

    @JsonProperty("application/zip")
    private String zip;

    @JsonProperty("image/jpeg")
    private String image;

//getters, setters and toString..
}
```

I'm getting the result of the other keys (its just a json object with name, author, etc) without problems but with this key i'm getting null.
How could i get this information properly then? (I've looking for a while now but other answers didn't work)

Comment: Where is the code that associates "formats" with Format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @SerializedName annotation. This annotation indicates the annotated member should be serialized to JSON with the provided name value as its field name.

raw/formats_sample.json

```
{
   "formats":{
      "application/x-mobipocket-ebook":"http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/84.kindle.images",
      "text/plain; charset=utf-8":"http://www.gutenberg.org/files/84/84-0.zip",
      "text/html; charset=utf-8":"http://www.gutenberg.org/files/84/84-h/84-h.htm",
      "application/rdf+xml":"http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/84.rdf",
      "application/epub+zip":"http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/84.epub.images",
      "application/zip":"http://www.gutenberg.org/files/84/84-h.zip",
      "image/jpeg":"http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/84/pg84.cover.small.jpg"
   }
}
```

Then in Format class add SerializedName annotation in your attributes

```
class Format {

    @SerializedName("application/x-mobipocket-ebook")
    private String ebook;

    @SerializedName("text/plain; charset=utf-8")
    private String textPlain;

    @SerializedName("text/html; charset=utf-8")
    private String textHtml;

    @SerializedName("application/rdf+xml")
    private String textXml;

    @SerializedName("application/epub+zip")
    private String epubZip;

    @SerializedName("application/zip")
    private String zip;

    @SerializedName("image/jpeg")
    private String image;
    
//getters, setters and toString..
}
```

And that's it, have fun!

```
gson.fromJson(FileUtils.loadFromRaw(context, R.raw.formats_sample), Format::class)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried different annotations but this one finally worked with retrofit.